# How to create recurring Hangfire job every 10 minutes for only 24 hours

Tags: c#, cron, hangfire

When I have a new customer signup that does not complete the process, I send them an email with next steps.  I need to create a job that runs every 10 minutes for the first 24 hours after signup.  After that time, there is another process that takes over.  I schedule the job like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(customerId, () => new NewCustomerProcess().checkNewCustomerStatus(customerId)), "*/10 * * * *");
```

If I add a job start time to the job class:

```
private DateTime _jobstart = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Can I inspect that within the job to figure out when 24 hours has passed then remove the job?

```
RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(customerId);
```

Does Hangfire re-instantiate the job class every time it runs?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly.

Hangfire does create a new instance of the job class every time.
So if I needed to solve this problem, I would pass in DateTime as a parameter every time the job is created:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(customerId, () => new 
NewCustomerProcess().checkNewCustomerStatus(customerId, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2))), "*/10 * * * *");
```

And then in the checkNewCustomerStatus compare with DateTime.Now

```
      if (DateTime.Now > dateEnqueued)
        {
            //Job is complete
            return;
        }
```